# Passing data on an API call from parent to child container in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-slick

I am fairly new to react and I was stuck at something trivial I feel. So what I want to do is that I want to pass data from a parent component to child. My code looks like this.

```
getData(key) {
    let { getData } = this.props;

    if (getData.code === "ON") {
        Codeapi(getData._id[0])
        .then(res => console.log("Result is", res)),
        (error => console.log(error));
    }
    return (
        <Dialog
            key={key}
            side="left"
            onImageClick={this.handleClick}>
            <ReactSlick />
            </Dialog>
    );
}
```

So basically I am just console logging the result out right now but I want to pass res somehow to the ReactSlick component which is wrapped inside Dialog component. How will I be able to use the res data in the ReactSlick component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the data stored in parent's state to the child element as a property.
Change the state upon receiving data from API. Chaning the data property of the parent will propagate to the child.

```
getData(key) {
    let { getData } = this.props;

    if (getData.code === "ON") {
        Codeapi(getData._id[0])
        .then(res => this.setState({data: res)),
        (error => console.log(error));
    }
    return (
        <Dialog
            key={key}
            side="left"
            onImageClick={this.handleClick}>
            <ReactSlick data={this.state.data} />
            </Dialog>
    );
}
```

In the constructor of the parent component:

```
constructor(){
  this.state = {data: null}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use async/await to get the res first, then pass it into child component

```
async getData(key) {
      let { getData } = this.props;
      let res = null;
      if (getData.code === "ON") {
          try{
            res = await Codeapi(getData._id[0]);
          } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
      }
      return (
          <Dialog
              key={key}
              side="left"
              onImageClick={this.handleClick}>
              <ReactSlick res/>
              </Dialog>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Uncaught Invariant violation as react doesnt know how to render promises. How will i work around this?

Answer (score 0):

You might need a stateful component to achieve this. Save the response to the state and then get he res value from state to pass it into the Slick component.

```
export class TestComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      res: null
    };
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    let { getData } = this.props;
    if (getData.code === "ON") {
      Codeapi(getData._id[0])
        .then(res => this.setState({ res })) // saving res to state
        .catch(error => console.log(error)); // use catch for errors from promises
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { res } = this.state;
    return (
      <Dialog
        key={key}
        side="left"
        onImageClick={this.handleClick}>
        <ReactSlick res={res} />
      </Dialog>
    )
  }
}
```